# bootstrapper application rollback

Tags: wix, rollback, bootstrapper, burn, cancel-button

I am trying to create a Wix burn bootstrapper that installs my msi. The bootstrapper exe is working fine but the only issue is that whenever I try to cancel the installation in midway the custom actions which are added in msi is not get stopping. Can anyone tell how to stop and rollback the installation while clicking cancel button. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

A custom action must send `::MsiProcessMessage()` calls to provide the possiblity to recieve the cancel and handle the return code from that API (usually `ERROR_INSTALL_USEREXIT` or `IDCANCEL`). Then the custom action must exit.

If you look at some of the WiX standard custom actions you'll see lots calls to `WcaProcessMessage()` and such. We save the return code from those and WcaFinalize() returns the correct thing on exit. Check out `src\ca\wcautil\wcautil.cpp` and `src\ca\wcautil\wcawrap.cpp` for example code.

Comment: Could you please explain in detail how to stop installation by cancel buttton in BA UI?

Comment: Return IDCANCEL from a callback.