# Cancel Installation and Rollback using wix burn Bootstrapper UI

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn

I am using Wix 3.7. I am trying to create wix burn bootstrapper that install my msi. I have added two buttons in my BA UI for Install and Cancel. i am using C# for BA UI design.

I have added the follwoing code in Install button for launch installation.

```
  MySampleBA.Model.Engine.Detect();
  MySampleBA.hwnd = IntPtr.Zero;          
  MySampleBA.Model.Bootstrapper.PlanBegin += this.PlanBegin;
  MySampleBA.Model.Bootstrapper.DetectPackageComplete += this.DetectedPackage;
  MySampleBA.Model.Bootstrapper.DetectComplete += this.DetectComplete;
  MySampleBA.Model.Bootstrapper.PlanPackageBegin += this.PlanPackageBegin;
  MySampleBA.Model.Bootstrapper.PlanComplete += this.PlanComplete;
  MySampleBA.Model.Bootstrapper.ExecuteMsiMessage += this.ExecuteMsiMessage;
  MySampleBA.Model.Bootstrapper.ExecuteProgress += this.ApplyExecuteProgress;
  MySampleBA.Model.Bootstrapper.PlanMsiFeature += this.PlanMsiFeature;
  MySampleBA.Model.Bootstrapper.PlanPackageComplete += this.PlanPackageComplete;
  MySampleBA.Model.Bootstrapper.Progress += this.ApplyProgress;
  MySampleBA.Model.Bootstrapper.CacheAcquireProgress += this.CacheAcquireProgress;
  MySampleBA.Model.Bootstrapper.CacheComplete += this.CacheComplete;
  MySampleBA.Model.Bootstrapper.Error += this.ExecuteError;
  MySampleBA.Model.Bootstrapper.ExecutePackageComplete += this.ExecuteComplte;
```

and launch install by using

```
  MySampleBA.Model.Engine.Plan(LaunchAction.Install);
  MySampleBA.Model.Engine.Apply(MySampleBA.hwnd);
```

The installation is working fine. But i have a problem with cancel the installation at mid.

I saw **[bootstrapper application rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177489/bootstrapper-application-rollback)** link. But i can't able to get an idea about IDCANCEL and How to trigger the Error event from button click.

Can anyone tell how to stop the installation by clicking cancel button which is in BA UI in detail?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many of the callbacks (like `Progress`) will provide args (like `ProgressEventArgs`) to your bootstrapper application. In the args object you may see a `Result` property. To cancel, set the `Result` property to `Result.Cancel`. When the callback returns to the `Burn` engine, it will see you set the result to cancel and start the rollback process (or do whatever cancel means in that context).

Comment: Thanks Rob. I added the e.Result=Result.Cancel in ExcuteProgress, It get cancel.
I need one more clarification, I have some custom actions in msi.
I added the Result.Cancel in ExcuteProgress. So if i cancel the installation at the time of Custom action execution, installation get canceled after completion of that particular Custom action. 
If CA take more time means, i have to wait for that much of time.

Is any solution available for cancel CA execution at mid? any suggestion?

Comment: Send progress messages during the custom action and they can recieve the cancel and abort faster. You have to write your custom action correctly and it will work.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I have some problem in Cancel the Setup while CA execution. I have 5 custom actions with my msi. If i cancel the setup while 1st (or any) CA running, all other CA are called by sequence after the execution of that particular CA. I have set the value of `Execute` attribute of all of my CA is `immediate` `Execute="immediate`. Already i have a code Result.Cancel in ApplyExecuteProgress callback.

In the log file i founded errors like this.
`MSI (s) (10:D8) [06:05:32:442]: I/O on thread 2368 could not be cancelled. Error: 1168`
Could you please tell me any suggestion for stopping CA?

Comment: That sounds like a new question. :)